# Solving $8a^2(a+b)=4ab(a+b)+b^3$ over the integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve in  $\ \mathbb{Z^2}$:
$$8a^2(a+b)=4ab(a+b)+b^3$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

true if both $a,b=0.$ Otherwise, take $a \neq 0$   and $x = \frac{b}{a}.$ Your equation asks for a rational root of
$$ x^3 + 4 x^2 - 4 x - 8 $$ but there are none.